# QT5.2.0; Debian Wheezy: QSocketNotifier::type() segfault

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a multithreaded app that uses QThreadPool.  It crashes after a random amount of time (sometimes minutes, sometimes hours...) with a segfault.  I recompiled with debugging symbols and ran through GDB.  Here's the backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7231170 in QSocketNotifier::type() const ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff7231170 in QSocketNotifier::type() const ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#1  0x00007ffff724b732 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007ffff51d713b in g_main_context_check ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff51d75c2 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff51d7744 in g_main_context_iteration ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff724c023 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007ffff71fa2cb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff71fe33e in QCoreApplication::exec() ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x0000000000409bb9 in main (argc=1, argv=<optimized out>) at main.cpp:166
```

That's the complete backtrace.  It references/mentions basically no code within the app itself; it all appears to be Qt library code causing the fault.   Not sure what source from the app itself to include in this post since GDB does not reference anything within the app itself.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try running the program in a debugger, when it crashes, the debugger will break into the program, and'll be able to see the stack trace and also any variables. You need to compile a debug version of Qt, and then link your program against it.

Comment: Thanks.  Compiling QT with the developer/debugging symbols produced more useful output.  I'm going to open a new question that specifically deals with the actual issue now that I got debugging mode working.